# Legal sites for anime in Japanese (raw - no subs or dubs)?

Tags: resources

I was browsing on the internet looking for some legal sites that allow free or paid streaming of animes that are not subbed, are still in Japanese and are not dubbed. However, I can't seem to find any legal sites where I can actually find just the original animes that haven't been hard subbed.

Is there a list of legal websites that allow legal streaming of the animes without it being subbed or dubbed?

Comment: crunchyroll, funimation , animefreak

Comment: @Sp0T If only seen subbed there. No raws.

Comment: @Sp0T Funimation only does ugly hardsubs; Animefreak isn't licensed.

Comment: though my only basis for this comment is from Funimation's and Madman's own actions, i wouldn't be surprised that there are Japanese streaming sites but are Geoblocked to everyone outside japan

Comment: @Memor-X Yes, there are - a fair number of Japanese shows get streamed (in potato quality) at [niconico](http://www.nicovideo.jp/).

Comment: You may find some more worth poiting out [here](http://myanimelist.net/featured/1617).

Answer (score 9):

On Crunchyroll, the Flash streams are all soft-subbed (well, nearly all of them, some series are hard-subbed) and relies on the Flash renderer to display them. Crunchyroll actually sometimes streams subtitles (depending on licensing) for multiple languages.

You just need to right click on the Flash frame (where the video is being displayed) and you should see a list of subtitle options, including at the top "No Subtitles".

Note that Crunchyroll also does HTML5 video, so browser's like Chrome which supports AVC streams through HTML5 will *not* use Flash. These types of streams are still soft-subbed but the local renderer of the subtitles isn't Flash, and it's probably some plugin-type video player that does this, so how you turn off subtitles depends on your OS and how you've setup the browser.

[image]

Comment: I am using Firefox, Windows 7 so it probably wont work with my browser. I tried to reproduce it, but in Firefox it doesn't have any of those options. It seems like they were using chrome too.

Comment: My OS Windows 8, and can produce it either using Chrome or Firefox, with right-clicking on the video. I tried with both browser in another machine with Windows XP, also worked. The video I tried was Nyaruko-san eps 12. As far as I remember, I didn't install any extensions/add-ons in browser that may tweaks with how the video shown though.